# Repopulating HTML Form on history.back()

Tags: html, forms, input, local-storage

I have a website where users can register crowdfunding projects. When registering a project, there are two separate html pages:

1. The first one contains a form where you input info about the project, including an image.
2. The second one contains a preview of what your project would look like, and there is a "Go back" button, which takes you back to the first page if you want to adjust something.

The issue is that the 'Go back' button currently uses a history.back() function, which does not repopulate the form fields when returning to the first page. As a result, users have to fill out the form again from scratch. I'm looking for a solution that will allow the form fields to be automatically repopulated when the user clicks the 'Go back' button.

I've attempted to use localStorage to store the form values and load them back into the form once the previous page is loaded. Here's the code I'm using to store the form data:

```
const formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#projectForm'));
const formObject = {};
formData.forEach((value, key) => formObject[key] = value);
localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formObject));
```

And here's the code I'm using to retrieve the data and repopulate the form fields:

```
const storedData = localStorage.getItem('formData');
const formData = JSON.parse(storedData);
Object.keys(formData).forEach(key => {
        const field = document.querySelector(`[name="${key}"]`);
        if (field) {
          field.value = formData[key];
        }
    });
```

However, I've run into an issue where I'm unable to repopulate the image input field. I've read that this is due to security reasons and you can't manually change the file input value.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this task. I'm relatively new to web development and would appreciate any insights or suggestions.